# PPMD compression in Java?

Tags: java, compression

Does anyone know of a Java implementation of the PPMD compression algorithm?

I have not been able to find a Java implementation, but there is a C# implementation at http://users.senet.com.au/~mjbone/Compression.html that is about 4k lines of code. I'm not going to ask if anyone feels like porting it to Java...

Answer (score 1):

I was using for the same implementation, and couldn't find any. But I found that 7zip gives the source code of their ppmd implementation just in C++, not in java (at least, until now).

I used system call's to 7zip do compress the data I need, using the command-line version of 7zip.

Answer (score 1):

Please see http://www.example-code.com/java/ppmd.asp
and libraries to be found in here 
http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java.asp

Comment: I know it's been a while but do you know which implementation they are using or if there is any other tool that can decompress the files encoding with them?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a commercial closed source PPMd implementation [here](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/compression-features.asp). I have not tried it, nor do I know anything else about it or the company producing it, so I do not know if it is compatible with the 7-zip version of the algorithm. It does not seem to be a pure Java implementation though - it's probably using native calls in the background.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for very fast compression, you may also try the java implementation of Google Snappy found here: http://code.google.com/p/snappy/

Snappy is used widely within Google.

Comment: snappy-java is not an java implementation of Snappy, only a binding (java api with JNI use of snappy OS binaries)